# Better way to find Gameobjects without GameObject.Find

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

Using Unity, I'm working on a game where all `Gameobjects` with a certain tag vanish/reappear fairly regularly (every 10 seconds on average). I use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag()` to create a `Gameobject[]` through which I enumerate every time that the objects need to be made visible/invisible. I cannot call it once, on Start, as new `Gameobjects` are created while playing. I thought that it would be worse to access and change the `Gameobject[]` every time something got created/destroyed. Is there a better way to handle this. I know how bad of an impact on performance the `GameObject.Find` methods make...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way to do this. Have a script with `List` variable that can store GameObjects. Making it a singleton is better but not necessary.

This singleton script should be attached to an empty GameObject:

```
public class GameObjectManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Holds instance of GameObjectManager
    public static GameObjectManager instance = null;
    public List<GameObject> allObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    void Awake()
    {
        //If this script does not exit already, use this current instance
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;

        //If this script already exit, DESTROY this current instance
        else if (instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

---

Now, write a script that registers itself to the `List` in the `GameObjectManager`  script. It should register itself in the `Awake` function and un-register itself in the `OnDestroy` function.

This script must be attached to each prefab you want to add to the List. Simply do that from the Editor:

```
public class GameObjectAutoAdd : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        //Add this GameObject to List when it is created
        GameObjectManager.instance.allObjects.Add(gameObject);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        //Remove this GameObject from the List when it is about to be destroyed
        GameObjectManager.instance.allObjects.Remove(gameObject);
    }
}
```

---

If the GameObjects are not prefabs but GameObjects created through code, simply attach the `GameObjectAutoAdd` script to them once they are created:

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject("Player");
obj.AddComponent<GameObjectAutoAdd>();
```

You can now access your `GameObjects` in the List with  `GameObjectManager.instance.allObjects[n];` where `n` is the index number and you don't have to use any of the `Find` functions to find the GameObject anymore.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. This solves all my problems! You couldn't have explained it better. You have my deepest gratitude.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, there was a typo in my answer in the `OnDestroy` function where I used the List `Add` function instead of the `Remove` function. The `Add` function should only be in the `Awake` function. I just fixed that. *Make sure to update the code.*

Comment: Usually I prefer to execute external reference operations in `Start` instead of `Awake`, unless a very specific script execution order is estabilished beforehand.

Comment: @Galandil I understand what you mean. Not knowing which function to put code can cause issues like variable not initializing before being used. Although, I spend few minutes deciding which one to use between `Awake`, `Start` and `OnEnable` and decided to go with `Awake`. The two reasons behind this decision is : 1.The `Awake` function will be called even when that script is disabled. Without doing this, the script won't register itself if disabled. 2.The `Awake` function will be called in the first frame registering it so that it can be used in the `Start` update of other scripts.

Comment: @Programmer Regarding 1: it's not true, even though the documentation says otherwise. Try to `Debug.Log("Awake");` in `Awake()` on a disabled object in the hierarchy before entering play mode: it won't log anything, same at anything put in `Start()`. That's why nowawadays I split the self/others references between `Awake` and `Start`, and if I need an object to be disabled at start, I do it via code at the end of `Start`

Comment: @Galandil You are confusing disable with de-activate. You enable/disable components/scripts but activate/de-activate GameObjects. I am talking about enabling/disabling components/scripts from the Editor or through script: `script.enabled = false;`

Comment: @Rupture lol why did you un-accept the answer? Didn't it solve your problem?

Comment: My bad! Must have been a miss-click

Comment: @Programmer I misread script for gameobject, my bad. Anyway, I follow the same procedure even regarding disabling components, to me it seems a much safer practice to know that any object or component to be disabled at start is always done inside the `Start` of a script, with a lot of objects in the hierarchy once I went crazy to find which script was disabled in the Inspector (unless there's a way that I don't know to search more in depth by using `t:script` and some additional command to only show disabled ones, but I don't think that it exists).

Answer (score 3):

It's true that calling to GameObject.Find consumes a lot of recourses.

The point should be to save the result and use it always but I understand that you can't do that.

Other option is to have all this gameobjects as a child of one gameobject let's call it handlerGameobject. It will have a script that doesn't use GameObeject.Find it could getChild or transform.Find that uses less resources.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does help.

Comment: @Chopi You need 15 rep to up-vote. OP is new and doesn't have that rep yet so  cannot upvote. Although, he/she can accept answer which he/she has already done.