# Can't use array after it's been called from a seperate script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've pulled an Array I created in another script, obviously with the intention of using it and cannot get it to display the right length. I tested if it was pulled right by referencing another variable in the same script and that was correct, so I'm not sure why the Array won't work if that will. I tried invoking a second of delay before the test() function was called in case the start() was too early for the array to be filled, but no luck.
And yes, i've triple checked all the spelling.

```cs
public class Global {
  //array I am trying to access
  public static GameObject[] BoidsArray;
  //test variable
  public static int NumberOfBoids;
}

private void Awake() {
  Global.BoidsArray = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<BoidSpawnScript>().BoidsArray;
  Global.NumberOfBoids = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<BoidSpawnScript>().NumberOfBoids;
}

void test() {
  Debug.Log(Global.BoidsArray.Length);
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start() {
  test();
}
```

Both the array and `NumberOfBoids` should be `2`, as the array is filled with said boids as they are spawned. The array returns `0` but `NumberOfBoids` gives `2`.

Edit:
the part on the other script that fills the array:

```cs
BoidsArray = new GameObject[NumberOfBoids];

for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfBoids; i++) {
  float randomY = Random.Range( - cHeight / 2f, cHeight / 2f);
  float randomX = Random.Range( - cWidth / 2f, cWidth / 2f);
  Vector2 spawnPosition = new Vector2(randomX, randomY);

  GameObject newBoid = Instantiate(PhysicalBoid, spawnPosition, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * Random.Range(0f, 360f)));

  BoidsArray[i] = newBoid;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show the part that "fills" the array. Since arrays have a fixed length it's likely that you're replacing the original array with a new one.

Comment: i added it as an edit, hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BoidsArray = new GameObject[NumberOfBoids]` creates a new array and assigns it to the BoidSpawnScript object. `Global.BoidsArray` still holds the original array. If you want to access the current array in the Global script then you'll have to add a reference to the script and use that instead.

```cs
public class Global
{   
    public static BoidSpawnScript BoidsScript;
    public static GameObject[] BoidsArray {
        get { return BoidsScript.BoidsArray; }
    }
}

private void Awake() {
    Global.BoidsScript = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<BoidSpawnScript>();
}
```

In this code accessing `Global.BoidsArray` always returns the current array from the BoidSpawnScript.

Note that this is just a roundabout way of making the BoidSpawnScript a [singleton](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern) so it might be better to just make the BoidSpawnScript a singleton instead of routing it through the `Global` script. Also note that [using `.Find()` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715785/better-way-to-find-gameobjects-without-gameobject-find) and in this case you could just do `camera.main` to get a reference to the main camera.

Comment: oh man awesome thank you so much, yea its all a learning process so all the help is appreciated. coding gives me a headache.

Comment: Probably rather just a timing issue ... if that `Awake` was executed after the snippet that assigns an fills the array there wouldn't be an issue at all ... -> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html

Answer (score 1):

To further @GuyIncognito's answer.
You should go for a singleton instance like this

```
public class BoidSpawnScript
{
  public static BoidSpawnScript instance;
  public static GameObject[] BoidsArray {get; set;}
  
  OnAwake()
  {
    if(instance == null)
    {
       instance = this; 
       // Prevents the singleton instance being destroyed when 
       // loading a new scene
       DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    else
       // In case the instance is already assigned
       // destroys the object
       Destroy(gameObject);
  }
}
```

Then you can simply access the static instance from anywhere in your code like this

```
public class MyScript
{
    GameObject[] myArray;
    OnStart()
    {
      MyArray = BoidSpawnScript.instance.BoidsArray;
    }
}
```

Be sure not to access the instance in another `OnAwake` method. You might just try to access it before it is initialized and it will throw an error. So to be safe access it from an `OnStart` method or any other method that executes after `OnAwake`.

Comment: Depends on how he plans to use this imo. This is just an elaboration on the previous answer. By the looks of it, OP is not that far in yet. Giving an answer that he wouldn't understand would do more harm than good

Comment: Note that this also isn't a complete singleton-pattern ... it is missing a very important point: being a SINGLEton, meaning only allow one single instance of this to exist at a time and the other way round also ensure one instance exists all the time

Comment: @derHugo I have updated my answer so It better represents a singleton.